# Major differences between OpenGL 1.1 and current 4.3?

Tags: java, opengl

For university we are learning 3D graphics with OpenGL 1.1 via JOGL/Java, it is still about fairly simple stuff:

- Standard draw methods (`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_LINES`)
- Using Cubic Bezier Curves
- Drawing a Race Track / working with Vectors
- Making objects (Robots) animate
- Using 2D Textures

After this course I would like to continue with 3D graphics programming, I've had a few tries yet, and it seems that I will only be able to learn it well with building my own (simple) engine, so be it.

We are using OpenGL 1.1 on university because it is still fairly easy and basic, however I think that the industry is at version 4.3 already?

Can someone name the major differences, possibly in features, but more interested in the programming approach?
I've noticed that a lot of the things are done on the CPU side in OpenGL 1.1, though it has GPU-support already.
Also are shader-languages required to create good-looking games, or why are they being used so often, I found them (in my free time) abnormally hard to understand.

Comment: The **major** difference is that in the last OpenGL version many stages of the graphics pipeline are programmable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is the way  you can access the graphics pipeline.

Means the graphic pipeline of OpenGL 1.1 to 2.0 is completely fixed.
You just have the possibility to influence the GPU behaviour by predefined OpenGL functions. (`glBegin`, `glPushMatrix`, `glPopMatrix` .....)

Modern OpenGL enables you to have influence on most stages of the rendering process.

#### The programmable pipeline is divided into:

- Vertex Shading
- Tessellation
- Geometry Shading
- Fragment Shading

Current GPUs offer drivers which can be programmed using the OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) to dynamically program every stage of the rendering process.

#### Pipeline References:

- Fixed-Fnction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-function
- Programmable (GLSL): http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/

---

#### UPDATE, due to comment:

Since you are able to customize every stage of the rendering process you have to implement appropriate shader programs to achieve Lighting, Shadowing and even projection on your own. This seams to be bad for the beginning but you have many tutorial to get in touch with it and some functions of OpenGL you can still use since they are backward compatible.
Me for example is still using the `gluPerspective` function to create the projection matrix.

Have a look here: http://open.gl/introduction
This is a really sophisticated and understandable tutorial to get in touch with modern OpenGL.

Here are some links to API's which support you in
programming modern OpenGL

- **glm** : http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html
  glm offers you all necessary math and is completely compatible to GLSL
  in my opinion glm is a must have
- **glfw** : http://www.glfw.org/
  glfw offers you functions to create and initialize the graphics context
  It is the interface to the operating system, the screen and the GPU
  additionally you are able to apply multithreading to your application.
- **SOIL** : http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html
  SOIL is a nice API to load textures from files

Comment: I'm used to a `glBegin()` ... `glVertex3d`/`glNormal3d`/`glTexture2d`/`glEnd` structure, in what way does GLSL change that part? Shader-language implies to me that it is about calculating/drawing shadows, special effects, etc. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: GLSL change that part in the way that you have to implement it on your own. But there are API which support you doin it. e.g glm, glfw and and.. Also have a look to the my edit. Additionally you have many examples and tutorials which just show you how to implement lighting and shadowing and so.

Comment: **+1**: Nice to see language like ***can*** instead of ***have to***. A lot of answers to this question would assume that 4.3 automatically prohibits using fixed-function OpenGL. But this distinction actually comes down to core/compatibility.

Comment: @Andon M Coleman thx. And of course you are right concerning the core/compatibly.

Comment: @Diversity: Don't forget the deprecation of the immediate mode and that in OpenGL-4.3 core VBOs and VAOs are mandatory. Also in OpenGL-2.x there were already shaders, so it wasn't purely fixed function.

Comment: Just remember that implementors offering >= 3.2 MUST offer Core, but may not offer Compatibility. Primary example: Apple.

Comment: @datenwolf Thx. Nice to know that. Many tutorials within the internet just show the deprecated pipeline. Additionally to really get in touch with modern OpenGL you have to really read the current books about it.

Comment: @peppe Thats right, i have the problem right now with Mac and XCode. Especially the compatibility to the GLSL language. Sometimes i really don't know what function to use eg. glReadBuffer or glReadBufferARB and so on. It is really hard to programm OpenGL on Mac.

Comment: @Diversity: and `gluPerspective` isn't an OpenGL function. You might extend the answer saying that you can use any toolkit (Qt, GLM, SDL, ...) to hook the small remaining bits -- context+surface creation, matrices/vectors manipulation, etc. (Qt actually goes full scale and offers tons of wrappers.)

Comment: @peppe K. Nice suggestion.